# Why does this template argument deduction/overload resolution fail?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

This code snippet fails to compile in [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/OYAVY7), [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/TOn56L) and [Gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/PupawT), (they give different error message):

```
int foo(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

template <class Ret, class A, class B>
void foo(Ret (*)(A, B)) {

}

int main() {
    foo(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't this compile? I can't see why it fails in resolving the overloaded function or in deducing the template arguments. Any help is welcome, thanks.

PS: It compiles if the template is replaced with `void foo(int (*)(int, int))`, or if we rename one of `foo` to avoid overloading.

Comment: Recursive function template overload resolution? Good luck to whoever dives into that one...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For simplicity, let's call the first overload `foo1` and call the second overload `foo2`.

With templates, the problem is that you cannot deduce the template arguments for the outer `foo`, according to [[temp.deduct.call]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.call#6.1):

> If the argument is an overload set containing one or more function
>   templates, the parameter is treated as a non-deduced context.

Without templates, the program considers all possibilities `foo1(foo1)`, `foo1(foo2)`, `foo2(foo1)`, `foo2(foo2)` and chooses the only viable one `foo2(foo1)`, according to [[over.over]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.over#6):

> [ *Note:* If `f()` and `g()` are both overloaded functions, the cross
>   product of possibilities must be considered to resolve `f(&g)`, or the
>   equivalent expression `f(g)`. — *end note* ]

Comment: Maybe add that a non-deduced context means the template is [not considered](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.over#2) for the outer `foo()`